# Button images over the UITableViewCell are getting cleared while scrolling

Tags: uitableview

I have added three UIButtons with background image as radio button unchecked image in the UITableView's each cell and when Somebody clicks it the buttons image will change to radio buttons checked image but the problem is when I am scrolling the UITableView the checked buttons images are getting cleared while I am scrolling.

Can somebody please give me any idea..!

This the code in which I have declared UIButtons

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellSetup = @"CellSetup";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellSetup] autorelease];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.tag=[indexPath row];

myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)]; 
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton.tag = ++tagCount;
[cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
tagCount++;

myButton2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 20, 20)]; 
[myButton2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton2.tag = tagCount;
[cell.contentView addSubview:myButton2];
tagCount++;

myButton3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 20, 20, 20)]; 
[myButton3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton3.tag = tagCount;
[cell.contentView addSubview:myButton3];
return cell;}
```

-(void)selectRadioButon:(id)sender {

```
btnTag = [sender tag];  
NSArray *arr = self.view.subviews; 
UITableView *tblCell = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *cellAry = tblCell.subviews;

for (int i = 0; i <[cellAry count]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *content = [cellAry objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *contentAry = content.contentView.subviews;
    for (int j = 0; j <[contentAry count]; j++) {
        UIButton *button = [contentAry objectAtIndex:j];
        if (btnTag == button.tag) {
            for (int k = 0; k <[contentAry count]; k++) {
                UIButton *button = [contentAry objectAtIndex:k];
                if (btnTag == button.tag) {
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else
                    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding the three UIButtons ? In what method ?
When the images are getting cleared while scrolling it sounds like you are doing something wrong in the following method : - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }` How are you handling the `UITableViewCell` reuse in your code ?

Comment: Yep, something you learn about 5 minutes into programming a table with checkable buttons is that the table cells are discarded as soon as they scroll out of view.  Any changeable data associated with a cell (such as its checked status) must be stored in a separate array.  If you don't initially know the size of the array needed you can use an NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1):

use an array for storing indexpath.row for showing chceked check boxes see this code

```
-(void)goodClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *index = sender.titleLabel.text ;
    if([self.goodIndexArray containsObject:index]){
        //[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedRect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.goodIndexArray removeObject:index];

    }
    else
    {
        //[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedRect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.goodIndexArray addObject:index];
        if([self.badIndexArray containsObject:index])
            [self.badIndexArray removeObject:index];

    }
    [self done];
    [self.table reloadData];
}
```

Add this method as your selector for your checbox button and add title for you button indexPath.row.

This provide you the way for identifying the cell which having checked check boxes.

And implement checks in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

see this check conditions

```
if([self.goodIndexArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",coun]])
            {
                [goodButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedRect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
                [goodButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedRect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Use this according to you and get your problem solved.

Comment: I have added the buttons according to the above given code and I have 100 rows

Comment: No problem with 100 rows. what is the current status, your problem has been solved or not.

Comment: No sir,I cant able to do according to your code.still I am facing the same problem..Please see the method I have used for my button clicked event.If any correction is needed please modify and tell me.

Comment: In your code where you are checking that you checkbox is check or not always you set same image in cellForRowAtIndexPath.no if else, need to implement condition for checking the index.

Comment: Sir I am new to this and I have done by this way.In a row I can select only one button.So for that only I did this way.Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: You know basic logics and also you had done some tutorial related with table view or not. What i have written in my answer that is sufficient to understand if you can use table view.